# Issue with chosing between dates in SQL Server, error msg241

Tags: sql-server

I'm  trying to query this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.rate_all_ports 
WHERE start_date <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
  AND stop_date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

In the table I'm querying from the dates are formatted like `YYYY-MM-DD` so I don't know where the error.

If I query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.rate_all_ports 
WHERE start_date <= '2022-12-02' 
  AND stop_date >= '2022-12-02'
```

it works.

And if query `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`, I get 2022-12-02.

Comment: *"In the table im querying from the dates are formated like "YYYY-MM-DD""* Date and time values don't have a "format", they are stored as binary value. Have you made the fatal mistake of storing your date and time values as a string based data type? If so, that's the real problem, and you need to fix your design.

Comment: Also the string format `yyyy-MM-dd` is ambiguous in SQL Server with the `(small)datetime` data type, so is best avoided. Stick to `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)`.

Comment: The fact that `start_date <= 2022-12-02` works, though, suggests that `stop_date` is the `varchar` value, and `start_date` is a `datetime`, as you can't compare a `varchar` (representing a date and time) or "newer" date and time data types to an `int`.

Comment: I think I had a typo, it was was supose to be ```` start_date <= '2022-12-02' ````. It worked fine when I was working in MySQL, but you think I should change the data type first and foremost?

Comment: ***Never*** store date and data in a non-date and time data type.

Comment: Okey thanks. Whats better, change it in my python script or in the sql?

Comment: The problem is your design on the database; python has *nothing* to do with it.

Comment: Date storage datatype and yyyy-mmm-dd design issues aside, I suspect you may have some invalid or blank data in your tables.  Run the query `SELECT *
FROM dbo.rate_all_ports
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, start_date) IS NULL
OR TRY_CONVERT(DATE, stop_date) IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I did what Larnu said and changed it data type and then it worked :)